Perturbation solution of second-order ODE
I am working on a research problem where I need to understand the change of the solution of a second order differential equation in the presence of a small forcing term $\delta(t)$. The equation looks like the following:
$A\ddot{x}(t) + B\dot{x}(t) + Cx(t) = \delta(t)$
...where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are known constants.
My intent is to derive an expression for $x$, $\dot{x}$, and $\ddot{x}$ as a function of $\delta$. Ultimately, I want to find the change in the solution with respect to $\delta$, i.e. $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \delta}$, $\frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \delta}$, and $\frac{\partial \ddot{x}}{\partial \delta}$. The trouble here is that one knows $\delta$ at any point in time, but its (exact) derivative is not known. The resulting expression would (hopefully) provide some insight into how the solution is changing with a possible change in $\delta$ at some point in time (say, within a timestep). As a result, I thought it might be reasonable to use a perturbation approach, treating $\delta$ as a perturbation parameter. We assume:
$x(t;\delta) = x_{0} + x_{1}\delta + x_{2}\delta^{2} + ...$ 
$\dot{x}(t;\delta) = \dot{x}_{0} + \dot{x}_{1}\delta + \dot{x}_{2}\delta^{2} + ...$ 
$\ddot{x}(t;\delta) = \ddot{x}_{0} + \ddot{x}_{1}\delta + \ddot{x}_{2}\delta^{2} + ...$
Substitution into the original equation, collecting like terms, and simplifying, yields the following equations:
$A\ddot{x}_{0} + B\dot{x}_{0} + Cx_{0} = 0$ 
$A\ddot{x}_{1} + B\dot{x}_{1} + Cx_{1} = 1$ 
$A\ddot{x}_{2} + B\dot{x}_{2} + Cx_{2} = 0$ 
$...$
For initial conditions $x(0;\delta)=G$ and $\dot{x}(0;\delta)=K$, the solution for $x_{0}$ is found as follows assuming that the eigenvalues $r_{1}$  of the characteristic equation are complex conjugates (which is a reasonable assumption for this problem as we expect the equation to be underdamped, i.e. $B < 2\sqrt{AC}$):
$x_{0} = e^{\gamma t} \left(c_{10}\cos{(\beta t)} + c_{20}\sin{(\beta t)}\right)$
...where $c_{10} = G$ and $c_{20} = \frac{K-\gamma G}{\beta}$.
The equation for $x_{1}$ is solved by finding the complementary and particular solutions:
$x_{1,c} = e^{\gamma t} \left(c_{11}\cos{(\beta t)} + c_{21}\sin{(\beta t)}\right)$
$x_{1,p} = \frac{1}{C}$
...where the initial conditions for $x_{1}$ are $x_{1}(0;\delta) = \dot{x}_{1}(0;\delta) = 0$, so the constants are simply $c_{11} = -\frac{1}{C}$ and $c_{12} = \frac{\gamma}{C\beta}$, then $x_{1}$ is:
$x_{1} = e^{\gamma t} \left(c_{11}\cos{(\beta t)} + c_{21}\sin{(\beta t)}\right) + \frac{1}{C}$
For $x_{2}$, I believe the initial conditions are also  $x_{2}(0;\delta) = \dot{x}_{2}(0;\delta) = 0$ which means that $x_{2} = 0$.
Putting it all together, the approximate solution is:
$x(t;\delta) = e^{\gamma t} \left(G\cos{(\beta t)} + \frac{K-\gamma G}{\beta}\sin{(\beta t)}\right) + \delta\left( e^{\gamma t} \left(-\frac{1}{C}\cos{(\beta t)} + \frac{\gamma}{C\beta}\sin{(\beta t)}\right) + \frac{1}{C} \right) + ...$
If we look at the derivatives of the expression with respect to $\delta$, the result is simply $x_{1}$:
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \delta} = e^{\gamma t} \left(-\frac{1}{C}\cos{(\beta t)} + \frac{\gamma}{C\beta}\sin{(\beta t)}\right) + \frac{1}{C}$
Similar expressions can be obtained for $\frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \delta}$ and $\frac{\partial \ddot{x}}{\partial \delta}$ by first taking the time derivative, then the partial with respect to $\delta$.
Does this process and outcome seem correct? The biggest concern I have is the fact that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \delta}$ is entirely dependent on the initial conditions of $x_{1}$. In this case, being zero (I believe) at $t=0$ then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \delta} = 0$, which doesn't seem right to me.
Any advice on how this problem might be approached in a different manner is appreciated. Thanks!

Thanks! However, no, $\delta$ just a forcing function for which we don't have an analytical form, but it can be measured. I suppose $\delta$ isn't the best choice of notation here.
